# What is Java doing to for-each elements to make them of type object?

Tags: java, foreach, hashtable

This question regards how the elements in a Java for-each loop are treated. I have a hashTable which is an array of LinkedLists. The data portion of the LinkedList nodes contain `TableEntry<K,V>`, where K and V are key and value types.

I wrote a for loop to look through each TableEntry in the LinkedList checking for if a key equals the TableEntry key. The syntax was kind of ugly, so I thought maybe a for-each loop would be more elegant/simple.

Indeed it was simpler to write. However, when I finished my IDE complained that element.getValue() was of type Object, not of type V. I put a type cast to V in front of the statement and it stops complaining. I haven't tested this code yet, but I'm wondering, first is this an acceptable practice? Second why do the elements end up as type Object even though they have the methods of type V?

```
@Override
public V getValue(K key)
{
    int index = getHashIndex(key);
    if(hashTable[index] != null)
    {

        //Standard for loop
        for(int i = 0; hashTable[index].get(i) != null; i++)
        {
            if(hashTable[index].get(i).getKey().equals(key))
            {
                return hashTable[index].get(i).getValue();
            }
        }

        //For-each loop should do same thing?
        for(TableEntry element : hashTable[index])
        {
            if(element.getKey().equals(key))
            {
                return (V) element.getValue();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You omitted the generic parameters in your enhanced for loop. So your `TableEntry` basically defaults to `TableEntry<Object, Object>` (an IDE will highlight this un-genericized use and a compiler will warn of it. Try changing you enhanced-for to include the necessary parameters:

```
for(TableEntry<K, V> element : hashTable[index]) {
    if(element.getKey().equals(key)) {
        return element.getValue();
    }
}
```

As to why your 'standard' loop works, your hash table must be declared with generic parameters, so the compiler knows the types you are attempting to access.

Comment: Ah yeah that fixes it, my mistake. Thanks! Will accept this answer when it lets me to anyone else checking this question.